# Ruby Sinatra - Protecting routes with authentication

Tags: ruby, authentication, routes, sinatra

I have a Ruby class that basically authenticates a user to an LDAP directory as follows. The `DirectoryUser` class is using the net/ldap gem to do this. When called the class returns either a 'true' if the user is authenticated or 'false' if not.

```
>>DirectoryUser.authenticate('user', 'password')
  #True
```

I want to use this mechanism to protect my routes in a basic Sinatra application for multiple users.

1. Is there a recommended way to do this that follows best practise?
2. Could somebody show how this could be achieved?

I was thinking of just setting a variable and checking the status of the variable before allowing access to the route. However, I can't help thinking there are some security implications that I could be missing here!

Answer (score 1):

It's in the [Sinatra FAQ.](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#auth)

Basically you need to create a helper method that will throw an exception if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: Yes I did see that - however it seems to only refer to HTTP based auth. I will be creating a form to get the 'user' and 'password' values, then passing it directly to the DirectoryUser class. I'm not sure if I can use the same type of helper method to do this!

Comment: Ok, sounds like you need sessions. This site has some great info on how to incorporate authentication into sessions: http://www.128bitstudios.com/2011/11/21/authentication-with-sinatra/

Comment: Hmm - Still having problems getting this off the ground - surely somebody has done this before! I lloked at the link above but there's a whole load of other things it seems to do. I just need a basic way to control access to my routes based on the user being authenticated via the DirectoryUser class!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using the LDAP library to authenticate, the best practice would be to use something like [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) for authorization.  We've gotten good use out of this app using multiple authentication methods (basic auth, twitter auth, LDAP auth).