# How do I do a really simple Sinatra LDAP authentication?

Tags: ruby, ldap, sinatra

I looked at the Sinatra docs and they only seem to reference HTTP authentication. I'm looking for a really simple way to control access to routes based on a user being authorised/authenticated via an LDAP server.

I've already built a class that does the LDAP bit and returns an LDAP object if the user has successfully authenticated and nil if they haven't:

```
>>DirectoryUser.authenticate('user', 'password')
#<DirectoryUser:0x007ffb589a2328>
```

I can use this to determine if they've successfully authenticated or not.

As a next step I want to splice this into a simple Sinatra app that provides a form to collect the LDAP user and password:

```
require 'directoryUser'
require 'sinatra'

enable :sessions

  get '/form' do
    username        = params[:username]
    password     = params[:password]
    haml :form
  end
```

Then I want to only allow routes if the 'DirectoryUser' object exists:

```
get '/protected' do # Only if DirectoryUser object exists 
    "This route is protected"
end

get '/unprotected' do  
    "This route is unprotected"
end
```

I've spent hours trying to find an answer to this but so far and can't seem to find anything that works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby Sinatra - Protecting routes with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821200/ruby-sinatra-protecting-routes-with-authentication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably go with something like this:

```
require 'directoryUser'
require 'sinatra'

enable :sessions

helpers do
  def authorize!
    redirect(to('/login')) unless session[:user_id]
  end
end

get '/login' do
  haml :login # with the login form
end

post '/login' do
  user = DirectoryUser.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])

  if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    # Or: session[:logged_in] = true, depending on your needs.
    redirect to('/protected')
  else
    redirect to('/login')
  end
end

get '/protected' do
  authorize!
  'This route is protected'
end

get '/unprotected' do  
  'This route is unprotected'
end
```

Comment: Superb! - I'll try it now and let you know how it goes. Thanks for responding.